# ReactJS: How to put <input/> inside a Material UI's <TextField/>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make `<TextField/>` (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field) as `<input/>`. So I attempted the following:

```
<TextField
  hintText='Enter username'
>
    <input
      className="form-control"
      ref='username'
      type='text'
    />
</TextField>
```

But it is not picking up the ref correctly. When `this.refs.username.value.trim()` is logged, it displays an error that `value` is undefined. But when `<input/>` is used alone, it picks up the inputted text correctly.

What is the proper the way to use `<input/>` but with `<TextField/>` as wrapper for styling?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you need this for? `<TextField />` already encapsulates '<input />'. Your code looks like an attempt to add one more `input` to `TextField` by why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have an input field inside a TextField component

Comment: then is there a way to make TextField component to have those attributes (ref, type, className) the `<Input/>` has?

Comment: I haven't tested it but what prevents you from directly doing <TextField hintText="Enter username" className="form-control" ref=''username" type="text">

Comment: tried it out but it fetches `[object Object]` when it is supposed to fetch `[object HTMLInputElement]`

Comment: TextField is a custom Object not an HTMLInputElement, the result is correct

Comment: but I want it to return HTMLInputElement because that's what it would do in the `<input/>`. Is it possible to do it in `<TextField/>`?

Comment: yes, whatever you can do in the <input type="text"/>, you can do it in <TextField> component you don't need <input/> at all

Comment: I'm aware but is there a way to get it to return as a `[object HTMLInputElement]`?

Answer (score 0):

Material UI's TextField Is An Input So all You need to do is add another TextField Below it add styling if you want them closer

you couldnt do `<input><input></input></input>` in normal HTML.

```
<TextField hintText="Hint" name="Name" fullWidth={true} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

you just need a handle change function which you should be able to work out from googling if you need one.